# Uploading and receiving large files http-compressed with ASP.NET gives "unexpected end of mime multipart stream"

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2, large-files

I'm having tough time trying to send large files with HTTP file upload in ASP.NET.

The target is to transfer contents larger than 2GB, compressed to save the bandwidth. Sending 3GB uncompressed works well, all the files are received and saved correctly on the disk. Yet, when I use compression (either gzip or deflate), I get the following error from the receiving API:

```
Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.
```

The thing is that only when sending large requests (approx. 300MB is the upper limit), I get the exception. Uploading 200MB compressed works well.

Here's the upload code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(fileServerUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

        CompressedContent compressedContent = new CompressedContent(content, "gzip");

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/fileupload/")
        {
            Content = compressedContent
        };

        var uploadResponse = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
    }
}
```

The [`CompressedContent`](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Content/CompressedContent.cs) class is a class from WebApiContrib set of helpers

Here's the receiving end

```
// CustomStreamProvider is an implementation to store the files uploaded on the disk
var streamProvider = new CustomStreamProvider(uploadPath);
var res = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
streamProvider.FileData.Select(file => new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName)).Select(fi => fi.FullName)
```

Can you provide me with a clue what the problem is? Why is it that larger contents (larger than 300MB) appear to be compressed improperly while smaller are transferred just fine?

Answer (score 2):

Are you compressing the file in chunks? If you are able to send uncompressed files, then clearly, the problem is your compression routine. Using gzip or Deflate out of the box has limitation on file size. Therefore you need to compress in chunks.

**Tip:**
Debug your compression routine. Try to compress your file and save it to the HDD and see if it is readable.

Take a look at this [article](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=730)

Comment: The article is down!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a name to your input as below:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput"/>
```

Or use a custom stream to append the newline that ASP.NET web api is expecting:

```
Stream reqStream = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
reqStream.CopyTo(tempStream);

tempStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempStream);
writer.WriteLine();
writer.Flush();
tempStream.Position = 0;

StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(tempStream);
foreach(var header in Request.Content.Headers)
{
    streamContent.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
}

// Read the form data and return an async task.
await streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already came across both solutions: giving names to all files transfered done. 
As for the other solution: tried it before, tried it again now. I used FileStream to process the request as using MemoryStream causes OutOfMemoryException. Still nothing changes: uploading data below 300MB works and uploading larger contents causes the error mentioned :(

Answer (score 1):

Check what is `content-length`, HTTP server side routine does not expect you to send different content-length. You are probably sending content-length of original file size, where else you are sending compressed content and MultiPart parser is expecting data equal to content-length.

Instead, you send a zipped file and extract it on server side and let both zipping and unzipping be different at application level instead of plugging inside http protocol.

You will have to make sure, order of compression/decompression and content-length are correct on both side. As far as I am aware, compression on upload is not very common on HTTP protocol.